# GetScriptReferences does not get called

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax, iscriptcontrol

I have written a Custom Control that contains the following:

```
[assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("InSysControls.AssignmentLists.AssignmentLists.js", "text/javascript")]
namespace InSysControls
{
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:AssignmentLists ID='AssignmentListsID' runat=\"server\"> </{0}:AssignmentLists>"), ParseChildren(true, "Items")]
    public class AssignmentLists : CompositeDataBoundControl, IScriptControl, INamingContainer
    {
        #region IScriptControl Members

        public IEnumerable<ScriptDescriptor> GetScriptDescriptors() {
            ScriptControlDescriptor descriptor = new ScriptControlDescriptor(this.GetType().FullName, this.ClientID);
            yield return descriptor;
        }

        public IEnumerable<ScriptReference> GetScriptReferences() {
            yield return new ScriptReference("InSysControls.AssignmentLists.AssignmentLists.js", "InSysControls");
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Does anyone know of a reason why neither GetScriptDescriptors or GetScriptReferences shouldn't get called? The other parts of the Control works just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to register the control as a ScriptControl:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{

    if (!this.DesignMode)
    {

        // Link the script up with the script manager
        ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
        if (scriptManager != null)
        {
            scriptManager.RegisterScriptControl(this);
        }

    }

    base.OnPreRender(e);

}

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    if (!this.DesignMode)
    {
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).RegisterScriptDescriptors(this);
    }
    base.Render(writer);
}
```

Comment: Ah that's right. Missed that. I bow in your general directions.